# regex to catch everything but the first segment of a URL

Tags: ruby, regex, url

Assuming I have the following URL: `/members/some/path/route`

I want a regex that will return only `/some/path/route`

So far I have `[^\/]\/.*`

But that doesn't quite work as it returns `s/some/path/route`

Can someone give me a hand here? I'd also like it if someone can tell me why my regex doesn't quite work so I can learn why it doesn't work.

I'm using ruby.

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript/C#/Java/PHP?

Comment: oh crap, your right!

Comment: right what? you didn't mentioned language name

Comment: Did you check the OP

Comment: ahh, sorry. I missed. just posted answer for ruby.

Comment: Programming questions (here and also on the job) should not assume that any particular approach (e.g., using a regex) is needed to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using javascript:

your regex will be

```
result = url.match(/(?:\/.*?)(\/.*)/g);
```

and your expected string will be held in `result[1]`

If using **RUBY**

```
if url =~ /(?:\/.*?)(\/.*)/
    result = $~[1]
end
```

OR

```
regexp = /(?:\/.*?)(\/.*)/
match = regexp.match(url)
if match
    result = match[1]
else
    result = ""
end
```

Comment: close but do you have one that doesn't use capture groups?

Comment: well I'd rather just use: `url[/regexthatonlyreturnseverythingafterthefirstsegment/]`  but this works too: `(url[/(?:\/.*?)(\/.*)/];$1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the second "/" and take the rest

```
preg_match("/\/(.*?)(\/.*)/", $url, $preg);
print_r($preg);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => /members/some/path/route
    [1] => members
    [2] => /some/path/route
)
```

But, I recommend not using RegExp, since it is a simple string, an [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function would do

```
$path_array = array_slice(explode("/", $url), 2); // we are slicing at 2, because there is a leading '/' at the beginning
$new_path = "/".implode("/", $path_array);
echo $new_path;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a regex for this. Instead I would use [Pathname#each_filename](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-each_filename) to construct an array whose elements are each component of the path.

```
str = "/members/some/path/route"

require "pathname"

Pathname(str).each_filename.to_a[1..-1].join('/')
  #=> "some/path/route"
```

We see that:

```
Pathname(str).each_filename.to_a[1..-1]
  #=> ["members", "some", "path", "route"]
```

This uses the class method `Kernel::Pathname`. I don't find the doc for that (which would be with the docs for [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html)), but we can verify:

```
method(:Pathname).owner
  #=> Kernel
```

This is similar to the class methods [Kernel::Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array), [Kernel::String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-String) and others:

```
Array(21)   # => [21]
String(19)  # => "19"
```

You could instead write:

```
Pathname.new(str).each_filename.to_a[1..-1].join('/')
  #=> "some/path/route"
```